# How does turtlebot 3 do localization?

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all. I am trying to understand the localization part of Turtlebot 3 Burger.
From what I understand from turtlebot3_core, by using an IMU to calculate rotational values from the wheels and translating them into odometry and updating it in the world_map.

Please kindly correct me if I am wrong and aside from odometry, may I know if the LIDAR plays a part in Localization?
There are a few localization algorithms like ekf etc. What is the algorithm employed by Turtlebot 3?

Regards,
Bobby

---

Edit: Hi Pujie,

Yes, I do know SLAM. I am trying to dive in deep about ROS for a report.
From my understanding, ROS localization works by Adaptive Monte Carlo Localization(AMCL) technique.
In layman's terms, just take it that each time I scan, I throw particles around and those particles are fixed and known as poses. Each time I scan, I know my position based on the poses I scanned with laser(kinect, lidar etc)

Odometry is using position sensors within the wheel encoders to determine the position. Using the information obtained from odometry and applying transforms(tf function with the mathematical calculation), it updates the x, y, z position of turtlebot 3 in the map, as shown in rviz.

I am trying to see if I am missing anything out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285652/how-does-turtlebot-3-do-localization?/) by [Bbybo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/33285/bbybo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-17**:
Please do not post answers, unless you are *answering* your own question. To interact with other posters, please use comments (for short responses) or update your original question by editing it. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you know SLAM(simultaneous localization and mapping) package, I think turtlebot3 use this kind of package.

Maybe you can search SLAM+Ros for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) with karma: 106 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1